# Minimum Element With Respect to a Cone

Tags: convex-optimization

We're asked to find the minimum element of the set S, where $S={\{(0,2), (1,1), (1,2), (4,0)\}}$ , and the minimum element x with respect to K is defined s.t. $y \in S \iff x \preccurlyeq_k y$. The solution is given as (0,2).

Why is (0,2) the minimum element rather than (1,1), when 2 is greater than 1?

Comment: What cone is used here?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confusing the inequality- it's the generalized inequality, rather than the conic inequality.

Comment: What do you mean by "generalized inequality"? The question refers to $K$, so we need to know what $K$ is.